# ArXiv how it detects TeX generated pdfs even if metadata changed

Tags: arxiv, metadata, tex-general

ArXiv only compiles pdflatex for now. I have a paper that requires XeTeX. Whenever i upload it to ArXiv it shows that i should upload the sources because it detects that it is TeX generated.

Any ideas how it detects that it is TeX generated, even if the meyadata changed?

Comment: what does the `pdfinfo` program report if run on your pdf?

Comment: How did you change the meta data? Which fields did you change?

Comment: I am voting to remove the off-topic flag, because this is a property of TeX generate document.

Comment: @samcarter I changed the author, creator, and producer properties

Comment: @Sari there are also custom properties which give away your compiler: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K7Jy.png

Answer (score 2):

arXiv's autotex can't process xelatex/luatex submissions. You need to ping help@arxiv.org and ask for an exception. The process for an exception is as follows:

1. Upload your source files into a submit-id
2. upload the pdf into a different one
3. ask for an exception providing both submit-ids and one of the admins will examine the source and the pdf. If we verify that we can't reasonably compile the source (as per my above explanation), we'd issue an exception for your xelatex pdf.

Comment: But how you detect if a pdf is tex generated or no. Based on what?

Comment: @Sari On pdf properties, we can find `pdfTeX-1.40.18` or `LuaTeX-1.0.4`, for example.

Comment: I changed metadata in which it has nothing related to TeX but still the system can determine it is a tex generated pdf.

Comment: There's a variety of checks that go into whether or not a pdf is tex-produced (including visual inspection). We won't tell you all of them for various reasons, but it isn't limited to pdf metadata.